# How can I display the price field twice?

Tags: entities, commerce

I am using commerce kickstart 2. Here's a screen shot of my product display

[image]

I've set a VAT tax rate in Drupal Commerce, so the price in that screenshot is the price of the product, plus the 20% VAT tax.

How can I display the price excluding VAT?

Comment: Did you checked this post ? http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1043/displaying-price-and-without-taxes

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Commerce Extra Price Formatters](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters) module.

**Extra Price Formatters Implemented So Far**

- **RRP / Your Price**

  Allows you to display the *Retail Price* and the *User Price*
  for a product and optionally the amount the customer
  will save.

  Allows you to switch the display back to a single price if
  there is no discount available on a particular product.
- **Formatted Price with Prefix and Suffix**

  Allows you to present a price in the style **just £9.99 ex
  VAT** or **only £9.99 for a limited time only.**
- **Formatted Price with no decimal places**

  When you are selling items with whole unit prices, you
  don't necessarily want to see £10.00. This formatter
  lets you change the display to show £10. (use this with
  care!)

There's a video demo here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WR3mKjou8M

Then you should add two *price fields* in your product content type. In your manage display tab you would be having a settings option to calculate your price excluding or including tax and other parameters and thus you can add two price fields.

Comment: The above answer does not answer the tax aspect of the question, and certainly won't work as described, so don't waste time on it. Adding another price field does not automatically fill that field with the product price. Rules or custom coding would be needed. But getting the tax in the new field is the issue (because it is calculated on the fly). Extra Price Formatters is certainly not the answer as it is designed to show discounts, not tax.